# Does every Matrix have a REF?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, wolfram-alpha

I'm wondering if anyone here has experience using Wolframalpha?

I can't seem to get a row echelon form (REF) or echelon form, it always does reduced row echelon form (R-REF).

Anybody know how to get this result?

Is the answer maybe that since REF are not unique, and there are a number of ways to get there, they just don't show any possible examples?

Comment: RREF is an example of an REF, just with the additional property that the final rows are adjusted so that the pivots have value $1$.  For most scenarios, if you want an REF, finding the RREF is more than sufficient.  As for whether there are multiple REF's available for a matrix, the answer is yes.  To see this, consider a nonzero matrix and find one of it's REF's.  Take a nonzero row in the result and multiply it all by $2$.  The result is also a REF of the matrix that is different than the first.  This is unlike the RREF which is always guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: The only scenario I can point to where the distinction is made necessary is when trying to deal with, say, integer matrices where you very explicitly avoid non-integer values.  The $1\times 3$ integer matrix $[2~~1~~1]$ does not have an RREF which is also an integer matrix, though it does have an REF (*and it is already equal to its REF in this case*).  Similarly other more exotic matrix rings may be such that it is not always possible to find an RREF of certain matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Wolframalpha a fair bit, but not really for linear algebra.

Another page I found very useful is the following, for matrix multiplication etc.:
https://matrixcalc.org/en/

It also has a separate page for Gaussian and Gauss-Jordan elimination:
https://matrixcalc.org/en/slu.html